# How do you use the twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I've just started trying to dive into the api. Right now I only know html and css as my background, and it seems the api uses a few languages I have no idea how to operate. I've made a working version of abraham's php-oauth. So I can log in and get some data back. But there seems to be no source saying do X to get Y result. I look at the API wiki and it just tells me what it *can* do, though not to do it. In short:

How do I look at the api wiki and turn a method into the code that tells twitter what i need? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated. Sadly, there is no "idiots guide to twitter's api".

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
function tweet($user,$pass,$app,$tweet)
{
    $url = 'http://'.$user.':'.$pass.'@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';
    $post =  http_build_query(array ('source' => $app, 'status' => $tweet));
    $context = stream_context_create( array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => $post)) );
    $connection = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    if (!$connection) {
       return false;
    }
    fclose($connection);
    return true;
}

Usage Example:

tweet('username','password','tehuber','Hello World!');
```

Comment: "IMPORTANT: Basic authentication removal is going to occur on August 16, 2010"

Answer (score 1):

Send POST or GET requests to the URL they tell you for the specified method, with the required parameters.

For example to [update a user's status](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses%C2%A0update):

The URL is http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.format (change "format" to either xml or json)

The HTTP method is POST ( you can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) )

The required parameter for this method is "status", all others are optional.

I haven't used the library you are using, but I have used [twitter-async](http://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async) for which there are [pretty good examples](http://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/blob/master/simpleTest.php) and I've also used [Zend](http://webhole.net/2010/02/20/twitter-zend-oauth-update-a-users-status/)

Look at this excerpt taken from twitter-async's example for updating a user's status

```
 $status = $twitterObj->post('/statuses/update.json', array('status' => 'This a simple test from twitter-async at ' . date('m-d-Y h:i:s')));
```